# Tabs in Xubuntu terminal showing up as characters

Tags: terminal, vim

I'm writing code using Vim in my terminal in Xubuntu 14.04, but when I hit tab, instead of showing whitespace,it looks like this:

[image: this]

I've tried to search for a solution but haven't found anything. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an older version of VTE (the terminal emulation engine behind GNOME Terminal and some other emulators) not recognizing DECSCUSR, the escape sequence that changes the cursor's shape and blinking.

Is your Vim (or perhaps Neovim) also from 14.04? I don't think they supported this feature 4+ years ago. Or maybe you got a config from somewhere that contains these sequences.

You could fix your Vim configuration not to emit these sequences, or upgrade to a newer VTE, or switch to another terminal emulator in your distro which either handles these sequences, or at least silently ignores them.

Note that 14.04 will receive its end of line in half a year from now, so it's a wise idea to upgrade soon anyway, presumably to 18.04. This problem is no longer present there.

Comment: Thanks, updating to 18.04 fixed the issue.